# Quantum Circuit for $e^{iAt}$ Hamiltonian Simulation in HHL algorithm

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, hhl-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation

In HHL algorithm, there is a step in Quantum Phase Estimation where we have to apply powers of $e^{iAt}$ to the register (see pic). I am not able to understand how to find the quantum circuit corresponding to this unitary transformation i.e. if I know $A$, then how to find the decomposition of this operator in terms of quantum gates.

As an exapmle, [Cao et al. v2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2232v2.pdf) , [Cao et al. v3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2232.pdf) -  in these papers the authors have decomposed the operator in terms of basic gates, but I am not able to understand, how they have done that. So, I am not able to understand how to decompose the operator $e^{iAt}$  in terms of basic gates for any Hermitian Matrix $A$ .

[image]

Comment: Converting a given Hamiltonian $A$ into a sequence of gates $e^{iAt}$ is called Hamiltonian simulation, which is a topic unto itself.  This depends very much on the nature of the Hamiltonian - e.g. how local or how sparse it is, how easy it is to determine entries of the matrix, etc.  HHL left the Hamiltonian simulation of $A$ as a black box, but there are lots of algorithms now known to efficiently perform Hamiltonian simulation.  Wikipedia [lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_simulation) a couple - many of these were optimized after HHL's paper.

Comment: +1 to what @MarkS said. In addition, the circuit implementing $e^{iAt}$ depends on the choice of basic gates. In fact, the circuit ranges from trivial (when $U=e^{iAt}$ is one of the basic gates) to potentially impossible (when the set of basic gates is not universal).

Comment: @MarkS thanks for the insights. If you have gone through the 2 papers that I have mentioned in the question, can you tell me how did they decompose those particular matrices into quantum gates?

Comment: I recommend you ask another question specific to the paper(s).  But briefly at the bottom of FIG. 4 of version 2 of the paper the authors provide the unitary which is equivalent to their $e^{iAt}$ for their example matrix $A$ given in equation $1$ of their paper.  They appear to rely on Group Leader Optimization for their Hamiltonian simulation, which I've not heard of but is discussed on this site [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3823/practical-implementation-of-hamiltonian-evolution).  Any further details you'd likely have to be more specific.

Comment: @MarkS Ok, I will make another post specific to the implementation of these papers.

Comment: @quankid Note that you can decompose $A$ as follow: $A = 3.75II + 1.25XZ + 0.75YY + 2.25 ZX $. Now you can use trotterization... but maybe there is a clever way to do this for this specific problem. In general, given a Hermitian matrix $A$, you always can decomposed $A$ in term of pauli string, then use trotterization to approximate $e^{iAt}$. If you are using qiskit then this can be done very quickly.

Comment: @KAJ226 May I know how did you find the coefficients of Pauli matrices. Also, can you explain in detail how can this be done using qiskit. I would be thankful if you could write a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As requested through the comment by the OP.

---

Given a Hermitian matrix $H$, we can always write it as linear combination of Pauli strings. That is,

$$ H = \sum_i \alpha_i P_i \hspace{1 cm} P_i \in \{I,X,Y,Z\}^{\otimes n} $$

note this linear combination can have up to $4^n$ terms. Thus, for a general Hamiltonian splitting it into linear combination of Pauli terms can be hard and inefficient. However, many interesting Hamiltonian have very efficient decomposition (the linear combination scales polynomial). For instance, the electronic structure Hamiltonian for molecule.

Now, the coefficients $\alpha_i$ can be determined through the formula
$$ \alpha_i = \dfrac{1}{2^n}Tr(P_i H)$$

So here, we are given that $H = A =\dfrac{1}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 15 & 9 & 5 & -3\\ 9 & 15 & 3 & -5\\ 5 & 3 & 15 & -9 \\ -3 & -5 & -9 & 15 \end{pmatrix} $.

so for instance,
$$ \dfrac{1}{2^2}Tr(II \cdot H)=\dfrac{1}{2^2} Tr\bigg(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 15 & 9 & 5 & -3\\ 9 & 15 & 3 & -5\\ 5 & 3 & 15 & -9 \\ -3 & -5 & -9 & 15 \end{pmatrix}  \bigg)= \dfrac{1}{2^2} Tr\bigg(\begin{pmatrix}  3.75 & 2.25 &  1.25 & -0.75\\  2.25 &  3.75 &  0.75 & -1.25\\ 1.25 &  0.75 &  3.75 & -2.25 \\ -0.75 & -1.25 & -2.25 &  3.75\end{pmatrix}  \bigg) =  3.75 $$

Similarly, $\dfrac{1}{4}Tr( XZ \cdot H) = 1.25$, $\dfrac{1}{4}Tr( ZX \cdot H) = 2.25$, and $\dfrac{1}{4}Tr( YY \cdot H ) = 0.75$.

The rest of the coefficients are $0$. For instance, $\dfrac{1}{4}Tr( IX) = 0$, and   $\dfrac{1}{4}Tr( YX) = 0$, etc.

---

Once you have the Pauli string decomposition, you can input this into quiskit to create a circuit that approximate (if the pauli terms don't commute with each other) the operation $e^{iAt}$ through [Trotterization](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Trotter_product_formula) ([look at page 207 here](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) to know more about this technique) pretty quickly using their `WeightedPauliOperator` as follow:

```
from qiskit.aqua.operators import WeightedPauliOperator
pauli_dict = {'paulis': [{"coeff": {"imag": 0, "real": 3.75 }, "label": "II"},
                         {"coeff": {"imag": 0, "real": 1.25 }, "label": "XZ"},
                         {"coeff": {"imag": 0, "real": 0.75 }, "label": "YY"},
                         {"coeff": {"imag": 0, "real": 2.25 }, "label": "ZX"},
                         ]}
operator = WeightedPauliOperator.from_dict(pauli_dict)
approx_circuit = operator.evolve(evo_time= 1, num_time_slices=1).decompose()
```

Note that you have option to change the evolution time and number of time slices in the `evolve` method. But note that all the Pauli terms here **commute** with each other so this is *not* an approximation but exact representation of the circuit. The reason is if $A$ and $B$ are two commuting matrix, $[A,B] = AB - BA = 0$, then $e^{A+B} = e^Ae^B $. Here $II$ commute with everything, and $[XZ,ZX] = 0$, $[ZX,YY] = 0$, and $[XZ,YY] = 0$ .

Which would output something like:

[image]

and if you want to transpiled to a specific gate set that you want to use, you can use the `transpile` function:

```
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
transpiled_circuit = transpile(approx_circuit, basis_gates=['cx', 'u3'], optimization_level = 3)
```

[image]

Then now, if you want to create the controlled version of $Controlled-e^{iAt}$ then you can create a controlled gate to all the gates you have in the circuit. But then you would still need to decompose those controlled operations to native gates that matches the device's native gate set. You can also do this automatically with qiskit too, actually. That is, you can just create a controlled version of the entire circuit above. Let's suppose the circuit to simulate $e^{iAt}$ is described as the `transpiled_circuit` we have above, then what I can do is:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit
xs_gate = transpiled_circuit.to_gate()
cxs_gate = xs_gate.control()
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q)
circuit.append(cxs_gate, [0,1,2])
```

This will create the circuit:

[image]

where the `circuit231` represents the entire `transpiled_circuit` we had above. You can then again* decompose this circuit to see what it would look like in term of more elementary gates:

```
decomposed_circuit = circuit.decompose().decompose()
```

which can give you something ridiculously long:

[image]

---

What I described is for a general case. For specific problem, you can use different tricks to make this neater. For instance, [see this amazing answer by Adam](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16574/9858).

Comment: KAJ226, I think there is a typo: it should be $\frac{1}{4}Tr(XZ \cdot H)$ instead of $\frac{1}{4}Tr(XZ)$ and similarly, for the other terms, am I right?

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan Yes! Thank you! :)